# Android Studio : Can't connect to mobile device

Tags: android, android-studio

**Android Studio Problems**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNMVy.png)

Hello,
I cannot see my phone(LG G6) in the Available Devices Tab after factory reset(used to be working fine).
Other Virtual Devices are working fine.

From the Troubleshooting Device Connections

- Step1 : Connect your device over USB [ I can see my phone G6 on the list ]
- Step2 : Enable USB Debugging [ Already done that ]
- Step3 : Restart the ADB server [ **No Android devices detected.** ]

Here's what I have tried

- Check if phone can be accessed through This PC
- Enable transfer on phone USB connection
- Enable USB Debugging
- Update Driver Software on Computer Management
- Check if ADB is working
- Redownload USB Google Driver

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try "Revoke USB debugging authorization" option in developer options of your device?

Comment: Yes, Just now and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to revoke the usb sessions in the developer options, then try downloading an [oem usb driver](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb)
If then doesn’t help you can try opening the device manager on windows, right click on your phone, select uninstall. This worked for me if I had the same issue.

Ps: you should download your driver [here](http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware)

Comment: Downloading the LG Mobile Driver on computer works for me.
Thanks!!

Comment: Already did that but it says vote with less than 15 reputations are recorded but not showed publicy